# Celery: Structuring sequential tasks and getting the correct status

Tags: django, task, celery, chain, chord

What is the best way to structure a bunch of sequential tasks using Celery? My code has a bunch of independent tasks (so they can all be immutable signatures), but I want to stop the sequence if one of the tasks throws an exception.

I've been searching for a solution to this, but I'm stuck. We're using Celery 3.1.12 + RabbitMQ.

At first, we used a chord to state that the header task succeeds in order for the callback to happen. It works great, except we needed to add more tasks to the header.

So I tried doing a chain in the chord. That also works, but the chord hangs with PENDING because the chain does not quit when a subtask raises an exception.

A contrived example:

```
@celery.task
def bite(food):
    if food == 'salad':
        raise TypeError('Throwing up. I hate {}'.format(food))
    print "bite {}...".format(food)
    return True

@celery.task
def chew(food):
    print "chewing {}...".format(food)
    return True

@celery.task
def swallow(food):
    print "swallowing {}...".format(food)
    return True

@celery.task
def chain_in_chord(food):
    return chord(
        chain(
            bite.si(food), chew.si(food)
        ),
        swallow.si(food)
    ).delay()
```

If food=salad, **bite** subtask will throw an exception. And the rest of chain does not happen - which is what I want. But the whole chord is stuck in PENDING status because the chain is stuck in PENDING and will not exit.

```
>>> res = foo.chain_in_chord('salad')
>>> res.status
'PENDING'
```

So I need to either:

1. Figure out a way to abort the chain and reraise the exception if the
   chain fails
2. Or, figure out a way to specify multiple subtasks in a
   chord's header (which I can't seem to do).

Searching online, chain apparently is behaving as expected - so you have to traverse the asyncResult's each parent status. I'd prefer a mechanism where the whole thing aborts and reraises the exception/trace... like a chord, but with the option to add multiple subtasks.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Someone recently pointed out [Celery-tasktree](https://github.com/NetAngels/celery-tasktree). Playing around with it and it looks promising.

The tasks above (bite, chew, swallow) can be implemented sequentially as a sequence - linking one task after another. It can be done with vanilla Celery also, but the syntax here seems cleaner.

```
def eat_tree(food):
    tree = TaskTree()
    bite_task = tree.add_task(bite, args=[food])
    chew_task = bite_task.add_task(chew, args=[food])
    swallow_task = chew_task.add_task(swallow, args=[food])
    return tree.apply_async()
```

And that results in:

```
>>> res = foo.eat_tree('steak')
>>> res
<TaskSetResult: 62c392ce-5ac2-4bd7-89f9-c1e004af1e56 [1b971232-2341-474b-897a-e5caab609eeb]>
>>> res.get()
[True]
>>> dir(res)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_args__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_failed_join_report', 'add', 'app', 'as_tuple', 'backend', 'children', 'clear', 'completed_count', 'delete', 'discard', 'failed', 'forget', 'get', 'id', 'iter_native', 'iterate', 'itersubtasks', 'join', 'join_native', 'maybe_reraise', 'parent', 'ready', 'remove', 'restore', 'results', 'revoke', 'save', 'serializable', 'subtasks', 'successful', 'supports_native_join', 'taskset_id', 'total', 'update', 'waiting']
>>> res.results[0]
<AsyncResult: 1b971232-2341-474b-897a-e5caab609eeb>
>>> res.results[0].status
u'SUCCESS'
>>> res.successful()
True
>>> res.taskset_id
'62c392ce-5ac2-4bd7-89f9-c1e004af1e56'
>>>
```

If one of the subtasks were to throw an exception, Tasktree throws an exception and marks the Tree as FAILURE (which is what I want), rather than PENDING (as in regular Celery).

```
>>> res = foo.eat_tree('salad')
>>> res.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/paulchoi/env/isd-python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 574, in get
    interval=interval, callback=callback, no_ack=no_ack)
  File "/Users/paulchoi/env/isd-python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 687, in join_native
    raise value
celery.backends.base.Exception: Throwing up. I hate salad
>>> res.successful()
False
>>> res.results[0].status
u'FAILURE'

>>>
```